# Get list of all articles in Wiki

Tags: list-view, wiki, wiki-pages

How does one create a list of Wiki articles found in a Sharepoint Wiki, preferably categorized by the first character of the page name? Basically, I'd like an list like the one at the bottom of this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Arts_occupations

I'm working on a basic Sharepoint 2010 setup and only have access to modify the pages through the Web interface. I'd like to avoid having to install any additional web parts. I don't have much experience at all with Sharepoint Wikis, so a step by step solution would be very much appreciated.